# Ubuntu 14.04 System Settings: Bluetooth is disabled

Tags: apt, package-management, bluetooth

I did something I don't know how to fix, and now I need help. I was trying to get bluetooth working, so I installed Bluez 5.39 with bluez-5.39.tar.xz from the [download page](http://www.bluez.org/download/) with `./configure`, `make`, and `sudo make install`. (I don't like installing stuff this way, and I shouldn't have done this.) It didn't solve the issue: it was failing to create LE connection. Then I decided to uninstall Bluez 5.39. (Why???)

From bluez-5.39 directory I ran `sudo make uninstall`. And then the real problem started: [link to image of message "Bluetooth is disabled" on Ubuntu System Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxny4.jpg). Switching bluetooth on or off does not affect the message in the left side.

This is what the uninstall did, and I only noticed important files were gone when it was already too late.

```
bluez-5.39$ sudo make uninstall
 ( cd '/usr/bin' && rm -f bluetoothctl btmon hciattach hciconfig hcitool hcidump rfcomm rctest l2test l2ping sdptool ciptool bccmd bluemoon hex2hcd mpris-proxy )
 ( cd '/usr/lib/cups/backend' && rm -f bluetooth )
 ( cd '/etc/dbus-1/system.d' && rm -f bluetooth.conf )
 ( cd '/usr/share/dbus-1/services' && rm -f org.bluez.obex.service )
 ( cd '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services' && rm -f org.bluez.service )
 ( cd '/usr/libexec/bluetooth' && rm -f bluetoothd obexd )
 ( cd '/usr/share/man/man1' && rm -f hciattach.1 hciconfig.1 hcitool.1 hcidump.1 rfcomm.1 rctest.1 l2ping.1 sdptool.1 ciptool.1 bccmd.1 hid2hci.1 )
 ( cd '/usr/share/man/man8' && rm -f bluetoothd.8 )
 ( cd '/lib/udev/rules.d' && rm -f 97-hid2hci.rules )
 ( cd '/lib/systemd/system' && rm -f bluetooth.service )
 ( cd '/usr/lib/systemd' && rm -f obex.service )
 ( cd '/lib/udev' && rm -f hid2hci )
```

Trying to fix the mess I made, I did the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 python-gobject python-dbus
```

And it throwed me a dependency error.

Then I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep bluetooth
```

And it installed `bluez`, `bluez-alsa:amd64`, `bluez-gstreamer`, `bluez-audio`, `bluez-dbg`, `indicator-bluetooth`.

And then the following seems to have been installed properly:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho libbluetooth-dev libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 python-gobject python-dbus
```

I tried to google for the default `bluetooth.conf` file, but I didn't find it, and I believe it's not the only thing that is missing.

Currently `dmesg | grep -i blue` outputs the following on the terminal:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    3.394321] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    3.394342] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.394346] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.394349] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.394356] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.084818] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    4.084824] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    4.084828] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    4.120553] init: bluetooth main process (811) terminated with status 1
[    4.120566] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
[    4.186711] init: bluetooth main process (924) terminated with status 1
[    4.186720] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
[    4.201162] init: bluetooth main process (935) terminated with status 1
[    4.201176] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
[    4.212252] init: bluetooth main process (946) terminated with status 1
[    4.212266] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
[    4.224325] init: bluetooth main process (960) terminated with status 1
[    4.224334] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
[    4.239237] init: bluetooth main process (973) terminated with status 1
[    4.239251] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
[    4.248063] init: bluetooth main process (982) terminated with status 1
[    4.248077] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
[    4.256712] init: bluetooth main process (991) terminated with status 1
[    4.256725] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
[    4.265736] init: bluetooth main process (1000) terminated with status 1
[    4.265751] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
[    4.274191] init: bluetooth main process (1009) terminated with status 1
[    4.274207] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
[    4.283039] init: bluetooth main process (1018) terminated with status 1
[    4.283048] init: bluetooth respawning too fast, stopped
```

When I try `bluetoothd` on the terminal nothing happens, but `/var/log/syslog` gets this:

```
bluetoothd[3517]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
bluetoothd[3517]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

The question has become quite lengthy because I'm trying to detail what I did so far. (And I'm not using any USB adapter for bluetooth.)

Is there any other log that I need post?

Bottom line: how to get bluetooth working again?

Comment: No problem. I often get help from Q&A at StackExchange sites, I'm not yet used to posting questions.

Comment: thx. Remember to choose the answer as the solution once it lets you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied the files below from another computer running Ubuntu 14.04 where `bluetoothd -v` is `4.101` too.

```
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf
/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
/lib/udev/hid2hci
/lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules
/usr/lib/cups/backend/bluetooth
/usr/share/man/man1/bluetooth.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/
/usr/share/man/man1/{hcitool.1,rfcomm.1,rctest.1,sdptool.1,ciptool.1} /usr/share/man/man1/
/usr/share/man/man8/{hciattach.8,hciconfig.8,hid2hci.8,l2ping.8,bccmd.8,bluetoothd.8} /usr/share/man/man8/
```